# Javascript - how do I use a variable within a function

Tags: javascript, string, function, variables

I'm a newbie trying to build a Texas Hold'em poker game for practice. For simplicity's sake, let's say I have 4 players and we are in round/game number 4, so my dealerChip will be at player4. Also for simplicity's sake, we start dealing at the dealerChip i.e. player 4.

```
var numberPlayers = 4;
var gameNumber = 4
var deck = ["1","3","4","2"]
var player4 = [];
var dealerChip = "player0";

if (gameNumber <= numberPlayers) {
    dealerChip = "player" + gameNumber;
}
else {
    var val = Math.floor((gameNumber-1) / numberPlayers);
    dealerChip = "player" + gameNumber - numberPlayers * val;
};

function deal(toWhere) {
    toWhere.push(deck[deck.length-1]);
    deck.pop();
}
```

Here's my issue - when I try to use the deal function on player4 directly (deal(player4);), it works fine.

But when I use the deal function on dealerChip (deal(dealerChip);), which is equal to player4, it doesn't work.

Is it because the dealerChip variable is actually a string? How to I change this? Sorry if the question is repeated - I'm too newbie to even know what to search for...

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: Perhaps you meant `"player" + (gameNumber - numberPlayers * val);` Make sure you look in the console for errors too - and have a look at `console.log`

Comment: *‘deal(dealerChip);), which is equal to player4*’ No. `player4` is *not* equal to `"player4"`.

Comment: Jeez, your article link is baffling. I started learning 2 days ago flat so I didn't know using the phrase "doesn't work" triggers people, but OK. Anyway, thanks for your input. I'm now looking for ways to convert "player4" to player4.

Comment: @Madna You have to understand that we hear that phrase **literally** at least 5 times a day for a causal user, and much more frequently for more involved users. I probably type something along the lines of "What is your actual error" at least 3 times, every single time I visit the site. It starts to get to you after awhile. For the sake of everyone's sanity, if you ever encounter a problem, please state as many details as you can about it. Did you get an error? Was the error runtime ro compile time? Did it just give you bad results? It's all relevant.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I understand. I'm using jsfiddle and it doesn't show me an error. Whenever I click run it just doesn't display anything (no error, nothing on the result), which is precisely why I'm here.

Comment: @madna Open your developer tools in your browser. It can usually be opened by pressing F12. With it open, find the console. It will show you any errors. When you're developing JS, just keep it open all the time.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oops, sorry! I didn't know there was such a thing. Thanks!

Comment: Np. It's an essential tool to learn to use. Browser's developer tools also contain ton of other useful features, like a debugger, and network monitor. You can also execute arbitrary JS code in the console if you ever need to test anything. Look over the tools for awhile. They'll save your ass many, many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you're trying to do. You need to make use of [javascript's bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```
//place properties into object.
var obj = {
    numberPlayers: 4,
    gameNumber: 4,
    deck: ["1","3","4","2"],
    player4: [],
    dealerChip: "player0"
};

function deal(toWhere) {
    toWhere.push(obj.deck[obj.deck.length-1]);
    obj.deck.pop();
}

obj.dealerChip = "player4";

//now, to call deal()

//what you do and works because player4 is an array
deal(obj.player4); 
//what you want to do; this access the property in the obj 
//that has a name equal to the value of dealerChip. 
//In this case, dealerChip has the value of "player4".
deal(obj[obj.dealerChip]); 
//Therefore, it can be rewritten as:
deal(obj["player4"]); 
//which can also be rewritten as:
deal(obj.player4);
//which is the same as the original you attempted
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your time, James. I'll go and dissect that! :)

Comment: Thanks so much, James! It works properly now and I'm working on incorporating it into the rest of my code!

Comment: @Carcigenicate Is that just the ^ up arrow? Done but reputation too low to be publicly displayed lol

Comment: @madna Above where you have him a check mark, the up arrow, ya.

Comment: @madna That's to prevent people from creating new accounts just to upvote themselves. A pain, but necessary. Many restrictions are removed once you get 50 rep. Just ask good questions, and you'll be there before you know it.